# Is there a way to hide the "+ Add column" on a Microsoft Lists?

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have a Microsoft Lists that has a view where I want to hide the far right column "+ Add Column" but I can't figure out how to hide it? (boxed in the image below)

[image]

Has anyone been able to do this before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no SharePoint/Microsoft Lists out of the box option to show/hide this option in SharePoint online modern experience.

However, you can manage this using **Permissions** in SharePoint.

Only users with **Edit** or higher permissions (like **Designer**, **Full Control**, etc.) can see this option lists.

So, grant below permissions as per your requirements to hide this option:

1. **Contribute**: If you want users to add/update/delete items from list
2. **Read**: If you want users to only read/view list items

**Documentation**: [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)